How do I write a function to rename the columns for multiple datasets?
I have 9 datasets that all have the same columns. I want to rename them all but I'm very new to R and haven't got the hang of writing functions or loops very well.
Here is what I've tried:
#create a vector of the column names I want to use
    columnnames<-c("Jurisdiction", "averagescore","DeltafromNatAve", "SigSymbol",    "PercentBasic","PercentProficient")
    #create a list of my dataframes
    naep_years<-list(naep2005,naep2007,naep2009,naep2011,naep2013,naep2015,naep2017,naep2019,naep2022)
    #use a for loop to assign the same column names to all 9 dataframes
    for (i in 1:length(naep_years)){
  x=naep_years[[i]]
  colnames(x)<-columnnames
}

When I run this code, I end up with one dataframe named x that has the data from naep2022 and the new column names. All of my original dataframes are unaltered.

(It's frequently helpful to combine different years of datasets into one dataset -- is there a compelling reason to do otherwise here?)

I think the issue is that you are copying your data to x and changing x without changing your data.
for (i in 1:length(naep_years)){
  colnames(naep_years[[i]]) <- columnnames
}

